# Node.js - request to database and delay

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I have app on Node.js, consisting of two files. First file contains function with construction `if(..) { ... } else { ... }`, second file contains functions whose result in an argument in `if()` and contains request to database. Example:

### File_1 (part)

```
var args = require('./File_2');
if(args.test() && args.example()) {
    //action
}
else {
    //action
}
```

### File_2 (part)

```
function test() {
    mysql.query('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = "test"', function(err, rows) {
        if(rows.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function example() {
    mysql.query('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = "example"', function(err, rows) {
        if(rows.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

exports.test = test;
exports.example = example;
```

The request comes after some time, so in `if()` arguments equal `undefined, undefined`. How to make `if/else` construction wait request result? I have two ideas - promises and module `async`. I think `async` - the wrong decision. How to use promises in this situation? Which solution is preferable? I will be glad to any answers.

(Sorry for bad english.)

Comment: You can't do do `if (someAsyncCall())`. It's not possible to call an asynchronous function and make it behave like a synchronous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

async is a pretty awesome library, but in node you will use a callback (not a return). Here is an example:

```
var async = require('async')

function test(callback){
  //simulate one async method call
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback(null, "test_finished")
  },100)
}

function example(callback){
  //simulate another async method call
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback(null, "example finished")
  },500)
}

function compare(err, results){
  //results will maintain order of array in parallel
  console.log(results[0], results[1]);
}

async.parallel([
    example,
    test
], compare);
```